# exit(EXIT_FAILURE) : the Tcl C API equivalent

Tags: c, tcl

I have this function :

```
Tcl_Obj* cFuncTcl (Tcl_Interp* interp, Tcl_Obj* obj) {
    Tcl_Obj *listObj = Tcl_NewListObj (0,NULL);
    const char* var = Tcl_GetString(obj);

    if (strcmp(var, "foo")) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } else {
        // Do something
    }

    return listObj;
}
```

I use `return Tcl_ERROR;` when my function returns an integer to report an error, but here my function returns an `obj`.

My question: Is there an *API C Tcl* equivalent to *exit(EXIT_FAILURE)*?

Comment: Your question is unclear - and possibly and X-Y problem.  If you are exiting, the process terminates, no TCL API will make a difference, termination is well... terminal.

Comment: @Clifford Yes, I use the C language to communicate with Tcl. `return Tcl_ERROR;` stops my program and generates an error in the interpreter.

Comment: Ok,  perhaps it would make more sense if I had ever used Tcl! ;-)  If my answer is nonsense, that'll be why, but I'll let it stand unless you indicate that I have misunderstood the question.

Comment: @Clifford I thought my question was clear, I want to replace `it` with `this` to have the same behavior (terminates the process). `return Tcl_ERROR;`  (I believe, not C programmer) do the same thing. Thanks `Tcl_Exit()` seems to suit me, I will test.

Comment: I think the difference is that `Tcl_exit` causes any registered Tcl exit handlers to be invoked, while `exit()` will omit that "clean-up" step. So not quite the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I use return Tcl_ERROR; when my function returns an integer to report an error,

Reporting an error via its return value is not the same a `exit()` which terminates the process.  No TCL API is required to terminate the process, how would that be any different than `exit()`?

If you want to return from this function with an error indication rather then abort, then simply return NULL - the return value is a *pointer* or an object, not an object itself, so returning NULL is the idiomatic way of indicating failure.

```c
Tcl_Obj* cFuncTcl (Tcl_Interp* interp, Tcl_Obj* obj) 
{
    Tcl_Obj *listObj = Tcl_NewListObj (0,NULL);
    const char* var = Tcl_GetString(obj);

    if (strcmp(var, "foo")) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "error\n");
        return NULL ;
    } 
    else 
    {
        // Do something
    }

    return listObj;
}
```

> Is there an API C Tcl equivalent to exit(EXIT_FAILURE)?

The API is [fully documented](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclLib/contents.htm) and there is [process termination API](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl9.0/TclLib/Exit.html) that includes `Tcl_Exit()`, but it is not clear that is what you actually need in this case.  You seem to be conflating process termination with a function returning an error status.  Nonetheless:

```c
Tcl_Obj* cFuncTcl (Tcl_Interp* interp, Tcl_Obj* obj) 
{
    Tcl_Obj *listObj = Tcl_NewListObj (0,NULL);
    const char* var = Tcl_GetString(obj);

    if (strcmp(var, "foo")) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "error\n");
        Tcl_Exit( Tcl_ERROR ) ;
    } 
    else 
    {
        // Do something
    }

    return listObj;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about a Tcl command implementation, `return TCL_ERROR;` signals that things went wrong (and `TCL_OK` would be if it worked). At the Tcl script level, that becomes a thrown error (with an error message in the interpreter result) that you handle with `catch` or `try`. It's up to the code that ultimately called `Tcl_Eval()` or `Tcl_EvalFile()` to decide what to do if the error bubbles up that far; in `tclsh`, the error stack unwinding trace is printed and the process exits... but that is really just the simplest option.

At the whole process level, use `Tcl_Exit(EXIT_FAILURE);` in C. Or `exit 1` in a script. Does what it says on the tin (after running critical exit handlers to do things like flushing I/O buffers).

Comment: The value of calling `Tcl_Exit` is that it also handles termination of a worker thread and overriding from the Tcl level.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. It's a pleasure to read you.